# Navbar Fade animation in scrolling with Javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll, fade, navbar

mainMenu is a big navigation bar that becomes invisible in down scroll and is replaced by topMenu, a little navigation top-fixed bar.

I have an issue: replacement is fade-animated only when topmenu appears. 
**How could I make the topmenu fade-animated also when it disappears?**

Here's my javascript:

```
<script>
        var mainMenuTop = $('#mainMenu').offset().top;
        var mainMenuBottom = mainMenuTop + 200; 
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); 

            if (scrollTop > mainMenuBottom) {

                if (($("#topMenu").is(":visible") === false)) {

                  $('#topMenu').fadeIn('slow');
                }
            } else {

                if ( $("#topMenu").is(":visible") ) {
                    $('#topMenu').hide();
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Which element are you referring to when you say "How could I make it fade-animated also when it disappears?". What's the "it"? Sorry, it's a little unclear.

Comment: Sorry, I'm referring to "topmenu"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is quite simple. Instead of this line:

```
$('#topMenu').hide();
```

Change it to this:

```
$('#topMenu').fadeOut('slow');
```

A nice simple jQuery animation. See http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/ for more details.

Hope that helps.